# When saving multiple videos with OpenCV, it corrupts the previous generated video. Is it solvable?

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

I have written a program that uses the web-cam to monitor a machine, and when a movement is detected, I want to save the ‘movement’-frames into a time stamped video.
However, while the program is running, the latest video is viewable, but the previous versions are corrupted.

Ex:

**Files:**

- Movement_11_25_01.avi (corrupted)
- Movement_11_28_22.avi (corrupted)
- Movement_11_33_21.avi (this is the latest video created, and it is viewable.)

And then another movement is detected;

**Files:**

- Movement_11_25_01.avi (corrupted)
- Movement_11_28_22.avi (corrupted)
- Movement_11_33_21.avi (corrupted)
- Movement_11_35_41.avi (this is the latest video created, and it is viewable.)

This is the code that runs in the end of every motion detected:

```
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Results\\'+self.name, self.fourcc, self.fps, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height))
print('Len Frames before saving video: ', len(self.frames))
for frame in self.frames:
    out.write(frame)
out.release()
self.cap.release()
print('Video saved.')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
self.frames = list()
# Open up a new instance of VideoCapture
self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

I suspect that the corruption is related to how the video file is stored while the program is running, but I cannot figure out how to save a video, close the connection to that file, and then create a new file.
Any help is apprichiated!

I have tried to close the `cap = cv2.VideoCapture()` and the `out = cv2.VideoWriter('Results\\'+self.name, self.fourcc, self.fps, (self.frame_width, self.frame_height)`)  by running  `cap.release()` and

`out.release()`  but with no success.  Only when the program is terminated, a uncurrupted file is generated, and it is the most recent file.

**Edit 2022-11-07:**
Here is an MRE that i run on windows 10, with Python 3.10.6, together with the modules numpy (1.23.2) and opencv-python (4.6.0.66).

I have noticed that in this MRE, the first file is saved in a workable format. However, the second and third file is corrupted. The main issue is the same, but reversed.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
from datetime import datetime


file_path = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(file_path, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)  # create a capture instance
        
startTime = time.time()  # Starttider
date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(startTime)


frames = list()
image = list()

frame_width = int( cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frame_height =int( cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

fps = 30


for _ in range(3):
    # Get some images
    for _ in range(60):
        _, frame = cap.read()
        frames.append(frame)

    # Initiate a video file
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D')
    date_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
    name = "v2Motiondetect_output"+str(date_time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y__ %H_%M_%S") )+ ".avi"
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(name, fourcc, fps, (frame_width, frame_height))
    print('Len Frames before saving video: ', len(frames))

    # Write out all frames
    for frame in frames:
        out.write(frame)

    print('Video Capture before ending program: ', out)
    print('Frames before ending program: ', id(frames))
    out.release()
    
    cap.release()
    
    print('Video Capture after ending program: ', out)
    print('Frames after ending program: ', id(frames))
    frames = list()
    print('frames after it is overwritten with an empty list object:', id(frames))
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    time.sleep(2) # Needed to ensure different timestamps
```

Comment: Could you please post the whole code including the class definition you are using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don't have access to it right now, but I can share it after the weekend. But the problem as I see it is within how the cv2.VideoWriter works, and somehow I'm misusing it. Do you agree with me, or is the information still to incomplete?

Comment: Without a [mcve] (and other relevant info, such as OS, library versions, etc) that would allow us to reproduce it... no. In the future, it would be wise to collect that information _before_ you post the question.

Comment: That makes so much sense. I will keep that in mind for my future posts and when I get a hold of the code (or a reproducible example) I will post it here.

Thank you for your guidance Dan, and happy weekend!

Comment: No problem. It is definitely odd that this is happening. One thing I'd suggest to investigate -- what happens if you rip out the `VideoCapture` and just write some fixed dummy image to the writer. (And since I see `CAP_DSHOW`, I guess you're on Windows? .. i suppose the backslash in path would be another hint :))

Comment: backslash looks ok (DSHOW usage already indicates Windows). VideoWriter usage looks okay. a video file being viewable first, and then corrupted, would mean you're doing something with it after it was successfully written. we don't get to see that. MRE is required, emphasis on minimal (no secondary business logic) and reproducible (complete, no thinking to make it run). also: [tour], [ask]

Comment: @DanMašek, I agree. Very odd. Hopefully it's just an error on my part. Good idea, I am guessing that the thought with that approach is eliminating a possible error source with the live webcam feed? I will investigate how this affects the output!

And yes, my OS is windows 10 (good job spotting the backslashes ;) ) running python 3.10.6 with opencv-python and numpy.

I will update the post with an MRE asap!

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Correct, it is windows. And i agree, the fault is most likely in the end of the chain. I will update the post with a MRE!